# Gradle generated Jar does not include gwt.xml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gradle

I created a small library project with the following build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'gwt-base'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url new File(rootProject.projectDir.parentFile, 'repo').toURI()
    //  url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
  }
}

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.7.0'
}
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
/library
/library/Library.gwt.xml
/library/client/HelloWorldWidget.java
```

The sources are taken from [here](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/tree/master/examples/library/src/main/java/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt/example/library).

When I perform a `gradle build`gradle generates a jar file which does not contain the sources and also does not contain the gwt.xml module file.

**How can I force gradle to include the sources and the gwt.xml file in the generated jar?**

Comment: See how the library is used: https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/blob/master/examples/war-using-library/build.gradle Not quite what you expected.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I did not get your point. How do I get what I expect?

Comment: Google for "include sources in jar".

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I also want to include the gwt.xml in the jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution to include the `*.java` files use:

```
jar {
  from('src/main/java') {
    include '**/*.java'
  }
}
```

The include any other resources like `gwt.xml` files put them into:

```
/src/main/resources
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
jar {
  from project.sourceSets.main.allSource
  from project.sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Comment: I agree that we should put resources like `*.gwt.xml` into `src/main/resources`. So that when builds jar file, gradle will include our resources to jar file. However, do we need to include `*.java` at all?

Comment: For me the only thing that I was able to get to work was the Alternative / last solution posted in this paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Java plugin, Gradle assumes that the project has the [standard structure](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), i.e. 'src\main\java' & 'src\test\java'. Therefore when executing the build tasks it simply doesn't find any of those directories.

The best way to fix this will be to define your project structure by modifying the existing source sets, which define where your sources are:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            include '/library/**'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            include '/test/sources/directory/**'
        }
    }
}
```